# Textarea draggable or resizable does not work

Tags: javascript, extjs, draggable, extjs5, resizable

Recently I upgraded extjs 4 to 5 then I figure out the textarea does not have draggable and resizable functionality but it works on extjs v4 perfectly.
I create fiddle to test it:
[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i5n)

How can I fixed it? This is a bug or I was wrong?

And this is the code that I used:

```
Ext.define('Textarea', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.TextArea',
    alias: 'widget.ddtext',

    contextMenu: true,
    root: null,
    name: 'text',
    emptyText: "Enter your text here",
    cls: "textInput",
    resizable: true,
    draggable: {
        constrain: true,
        preventDefault: false,
        stopEvent: true
    }
});

Ext.define('TestWindow', {
    extend: "Ext.window.Window",
    alias: "widget.ddwindow",
    title: 'Window',
    width: 550,
    height: 670,
    resizable: false,
    layout: 'fit',
    modal: true,
    items: {
        itemId: "windowContainer",
        autoScroll: true,
        xtype: "container",
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            padding: 5
        },
        defaults: {
            width: "100%"
        },
        items: [
            {
                itemId: "container",
                xtype: "container",
                layout: 'vbox',
                items: [
                    {
                        itemId: "dropZone",
                        xtype: "container",
                        height: 500,
                        width: 500,
                        style:{
                            backgroundColor: "#000"  
                        },
                        layout: "absolute",
                        scope: this,
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'ddtext'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create("TestWindow").show();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by either:

- removing the dropZone container completely https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i60
- changing dropZone's layout from "absolute" to "fit" https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i5v

Looks like there's some issue with having a resizable component inside an absolute container.

Comment: But there is still an issue when I resize the textarea, it has strange behavior, if you resize you can see the content of textarea will be half of size the border. how can I fix it? and what about draggable? @mcgrathg